# How to retrieve a set of objects, filtered and ordered by fields of other objects, for which the desired object is a foreign key?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-templates, django-queryset

To rephrase the title to the context of my problem: How to retrieve a set of foods, filtered and ordered by fields of other objects, for which the food object is a foreign key?

I have the following models:

```
class Food(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)

class DayOfFood(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    date = models.DateField()
    unique_together = ("user", "date")

class FoodEaten(models.Model):
    day = models.ForeignKey(DayOfFood, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    food = models.ForeignKey(Food, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    servings = models.FloatField(default=1)
```

I want to be able to retrieve the foods that a given user ate most recently. This collection of foods will be passed to a template so it must be a QuerySet to allow the template to loop over the food objects.

This is how far I got

```
days = DayOfFood.objects.filter(user=request.user)
foodeatens = FoodEaten.objects.filter(day__in=days)
foodeatens = foodeatens.order_by('day__date')
```

Now it feels like I am almost there, all the foods I want are contained in the FoodEaten objects in the resulting QuerySet. I do not know how to use "for ... in:" to get the food objects and still have them stored in a QuerySet. Is there a way to perform foreach or map to a QuerySet?

I do not want to rewrite the template to accept FoodEaten objects instead because the template is used by other views which do simply pass food objects to the template.

## The solution

The answer from Shang Wang helped me write code that solves my problem:

```
days = DayOfFood.objects.filter(user=request.user)
foods = Food.objects.filter(
  foodeaten__day__in=days,
  foodeaten__day__user=request.user) \
  .order_by('-foodeaten__day__date')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That could be done using chain of relations:

```
Food.objects.filter(foodeaten__day__in=days,
                    foodeaten__day__user=request.user) \
            .order_by('foodeaten__day__date')
```

By the way, I'm not sure why do you have `user` on multiple models `Food` and `DayOfFood`. If you really need user relations on both of them, maybe make the field name more explicit with the user's role in each model, otherwise you will get confused very quickly.

Comment: Thanks! Your code helped me understand how to follow foreign key relations in the "other" direction. There's a mistake in your code with the first filter argument which i corrected in the solution added to the original question post.

Comment: Oh and I forgot to answer why both Food and DayOfFood need a user field. That is because in my program food is not shared between users. Every day a user can only eat the food that belongs to him.